# how do i configure a static folder that is out of war with apache in a java project with weblogic

Tags: java, apache, static, weblogic

I have a project where the static folder gets out of the war package. I researched and verified that it is necessary to configure this by apache. But I can not find any clear content on how to do this.
I'm using java 5 and weblogic 10.6 currently.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the Directory directive in your httpd.conf file :

```
Alias /static /home/mysite/static
<Directory "/home/mysite/static">
</Directory>
```